# Is GenTraversableOnce[B] parent type of Array[File]?

Tags: scala, inheritance

Def of `flatMap` :

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Array[B]
```

To create a `List` of files within a dir :

```
 def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
    val these = f.listFiles
    these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(f => recursiveListFiles(f))
  }
```

`flatMap` accepts a function parameter which also accepts a parameter and returns 
 type `GenTraversableOnce[B]`

There exists a hierarchical common type between `Array` & `GenTraversableOnce` as if there no link then `Array[File]` should not be a valid type for `GenTraversableOnce[B]` ?

Looking at 
`Array` API : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.Array

`GenTraversableOnce` API : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

There does not appear to be a Link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the linked scaladoc of `Array`:

> Two implicit conversions exist in scala.Predef that are frequently applied to arrays: a conversion to scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps (shown on line 4 of the example above) and a conversion to scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray (a subtype of scala.collection.Seq).

`Array` does not inherit from `GenTraversableOnce`, but there is an implicit conversion from `Array` to `ArrayOps` in `scala.Predef` seen [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L313-314) and [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L334). And `ArrayOps` does inherit from `GenTraversableOnce`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit conversion from [`Array`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.Array) to [`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps), which inherits `GenTraversableOnce`.

From the ScalaDocs :

> Two implicit conversions exist in scala.Predef that are frequently
>   applied to arrays: a conversion to scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps
>   (shown on line 4 of the example above) and a conversion to
>   scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray (a subtype of
>   scala.collection.Seq). Both types make available many of the standard
>   operations found in the Scala collections API

As for the difference between the two :

> The conversion to ArrayOps is temporary, as all operations defined on
>   ArrayOps return an Array, while the conversion to WrappedArray is
>   permanent as all operations return a WrappedArray.